# How to get the remaining data from a select that returns random rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I select 20 random movies from 50 movies total,

```
SELECT movieName
FROM movies 
ORDER BY random() 
LIMIT 20
```

Then how do I continue select 10 random from the remaining 30 movies?

If I keep using code above, there is a duplicate key value error.

Comment: Use a cursor instead.

Answer (score 4):

Generate a random key `key`, then order by `md5(movieName || key)`. Keep track of this key so you can request the next set of tuples using `OFFSET` with the same key. Using the same key twice will result in the same order. Using a different key will result in a different order. This appears random because hash functions like `md5` return completely different results for similar inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the names of the movies that were already displayed somewhere. Then when you re-run the statement add a `where moviename not in (....)` to the query to exclude those that you already displayed.

If you can keep the connection to the database open between the requests, you can use a temporary table to store the already displayed movies:

```
create temporary table displayed_movies(moviename text);
```

You can then use the following statement to display the movies:

```
with selected as (
  select moviename
  from movies 
  where moviename not in (select d.moviename 
                          from displayed_movies d)
  order by random() 
  limit 20
), inserted as (
   insert into displayed_movies (moviename)
   select moviename
   from selected       
) 
select *
from selected;
```

Each time you run the above statement, it will select a different (random) set of movies. If all movies are displayed nothing will be returned.

Again: this will only work if you keep the connection to the database open between each call.

If you can't keep the connection open (which means you can't use the temporary table) you need to remember those names in your application and generate the appropriate `where moviename not in (...)` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your query in an new query like that:

```
SELECT       
   movieName 
FROM       
   movies
WHERE
   movieName not in (SELECT film_id FROM film ORDER BY random() LIMIT 20)
ORDER BY       
   random() 
LIMIT 10;
```

You won't see the 20 movies selected with your first query. In this case theres just the result of selecting 20 movies and than selecting 10 of the remaining 30.

Keep in mind, that if you are are using your statement first, and this query afterwards, the subselect(your query) will return orther random movies than by the first time it is executed.

Hope that hepls!

Comment: That is not going to work because the second execution of that query will return a different list of movies in the sub-select